# How can I consolidate repositories?

Tags: git, github

I have a number of repositories that I'd like to consolidate into one called Z.  so if I have repos A, B and C, I'd like to end up with Z/A, Z/B and Z/C.  in other words, each repository becomes a folder in the one repo Z

my approach was: clone Z, change directory into it and clone the others, but when I tried to `add` I got the following:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: A
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> A
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached A
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

but in reading about submodules, I don't think it's what I want because it's basically  a reference to a repo inside of another and I want to move this code

what I ended up doing is the same as above but `rm -rf A/.git` -- but of course, I lose the history and I'd like to keep it.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Well, you can, sort of, but overall it's not well-defined: what does it mean to retain the history of a separate Git repository?  The history in a repository is nothing more or less than the commits in that repository.  The hitch here is that we *find* commits using (mostly) branch and tag names, and while you can add as many commits (and other objects) you like to the commits-and-other-objects database, as each unique object has a unique name–its hash ID—so that no two names will ever collide, that's *not* the case in general for the branch and tag names.

Let's take a concrete but simplified example, where we invent two repositories A and B, which you'll want to claim as `Z/A` and `Z/B`.  Repository A has two commits, which were created on 1 Jan 1990 and 31 Dec 2032 (ten years into the future).  Repository B has three commits, which were created on (respectively) 1 Jan 1970, 1 Jan 1990, and 31 Dec 1999.

How many commits should exist in Z?  Two?  Three?  Four?  Five?  Why?

If your answer is two, what should be in the first and last commits and what should their dates be?

If your answer is three, or four, or five, what should their dates and contents be, and why?

Once you can answer this systematically, you can come up with a procedure for transforming the original commits into new (different) commits in your combined repository.  The new commits won't relate to the original commits in any way other than whatever your combining system dictates.

Submodules sidestep this problem by *not* trying to store some *other* repository's commits.  Instead, we make a "super-module" Z that has however many commits it has.  Let's say it has two:

- One, made on 2 Jan 1990 after the first commit in A and second in G, says: use the first commit in repo A, and the second commit in repo B: here are their two hash IDs.
- Another, made more recently but not yet using the future-dated commit in repo A, says: use the first commit in repo A, and the third commit in repo B: here are their two hash IDs.  The hash ID of the commit to use in A matches the one in the earlier commit in this same repository.

You can now make a third commit in Z if you like, to update the reference to repo A to say to use the future-dated commit, if you like.  You can have this third commit continue to use the third commit in B, or retreat back to one of the earlier B commits.  Z's only responsibility here is to say *which commits* we're to use *from* A and B; A and B retain their history, and Z has its own separate history, and all is simple, except for the fact that submodules are painful.  (Note that the superproject in Z does not use any branch or tag names for either A or B.  It uses only the unique hash IDs as "names" within those clones.)

Comment: thanks for your very comprehensive reply.  my expectation is that if a developer changes a line of code (e.g. s/he/she/) and leaves a comment (e.g. "fixed gender") that upon moving my repo to another, that this commit would carry across and remain intact.  it sounds like git make no provision for this

Comment: so my answer to your question: "How many commits should exist in Z?" is 5.  because Z should contain all the commits that were made in the repos it absorbed

Comment: OK - that gives you a guide for how to combine the commits: pile them all in together, perhaps in date order. (You now have to decide whether to use the author timestamp or the committer timestamp, and/or some other non-time-stamp criteria.)

Comment: You'll end up with a new repository, and if you want to add future commits to it, you'll be able to do that, but you'll need to remember a map of hash IDs or something along those lines.